# Where to open Xcode 4.2 Command line Tools?

Tags: xcode, command-line-tool

I need to re-code sign an ipa file. A tutorial explains recode signing via xcode CLT. For that first of all I need CLT for xcode. I am using xcode 4.2. So where do i find the command line tools for re-code signing in Xcode 4.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent versions of Xcode (Xcode 4.3.x) all the command line tools have moved to: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/`.

In older versions of Xcode (prior to Xcode 4.3) the tools are just installed in `/usr/bin` or `/Developer/usr/bin`.

Comment: Is there anyway we can open the command line when inside XCode IDE? Thanks

Comment: @user2451016: it depends on what you mean by "open the command line" exactly but there is a console window, and you can specify command line parameters to be passed to your executable, if that's what you mean ?