# C++ Hello World trouble on OSX10.8

Tags: c++, osx-mountain-lion

My profile is updated to point to what i think is the right location:

```
  PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:${PATH}
```

Compilers are found

```
[11:39:32] ~: $ which g++
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin//g++
[11:39:35] ~: $ which gcc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin//gcc
```

Hello world looks as follows

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Fails to execute both from command line and TextMate with

```
[11:40:15] Desktop: $ g++ untitled.cpp 
untitled.cpp:1:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
untitled.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
untitled.cpp:6: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
```

**What else should i have in my path and am missing please?**

Comment: Did you install the command line tools package inside xcode? That should put what you need in `/usr/bin/`, not inside `Xcode.app`

Comment: It's a little weird to to add ${PATH} twice in that line.  It shouldn't cause your problem, but you don't need it either.

Comment: This error message hints, that the header files cannot be found. Please remember, that headers and compiler are not the same thing (though they're closely intertwined).

Comment: I have nothing (gcc/g++ related) in `/usr/bin`, which is what i suspect the issue is, but i did upgrade `Xcode.app` to the latest, which i assume includes command line dev tools. How can i confirm that? How can i force the install of command line tools?

Comment: It appears that in Xcode 4.3, command line tools are in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/` as answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346369/where-to-open-xcode-4-2-command-line-tools

Comment: I am not sure if you found the solution, buy running `g++` with the `-v` option should help to diagnose the problem. It should tell you about the include and library search paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is, as always, obvious

Install Xcode Command Line Tools

[image]

Check your `/usr/bin` and find there:

[image]

Try again .. Everything works automagically

On a side note, it is odd that upgrade from OSX10.7 to OSX10.8 removed these links

Answer (score -2):

This answer is for GCC, but other non-vcc compilers may be the same. When I used GCC iostream was non existent, however iostream.h was, I suggest you try iostream.h and if you run into this problem again with STL headers add the .h.

Comment: Yes it is, however I was stating that I have run into issues a while back where iostream.h was the only header found, so as I am not a Mac user, it was something the OP could try

Comment: It is true that `iostream-h` was the header in some pre-standard implementations, but I doubt the version of gcc provided with xcode in such a recent version of mac OSX would be so ancient.