# error while 'sudo gem install eventmachine -v 1.0.8 ' on mac os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler

This is an error i'm facing while installing eventmachine on mac os, i've tried all answers but can't solve it till now and here is the error logs.

```html
<pre><code>Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for pipe2() in unistd.h... no
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for SOCK_CLOEXEC in sys/socket.h... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
CFLAGS=$(cflags)  -pipe -I/opt/local/include -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-unused-result
CPPFLAGS=-D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT $(DEFS) $(cppflags) -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-unused-result
checking for clock_gettime()... no
checking for gethrtime()... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:29:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.1.0-static/eventmachine-1.0.8/gem_make.out</code></pre>
```

please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:29:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
#include <iostream>
```

What's occurring is that the compiler cannot find project.h's include iostream. You could play around with installing it manually, link provided below.

https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Building-EventMachine

This link may help solve your problem.

[C++ Hello World trouble on OSX10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818189/c-hello-world-trouble-on-osx10-8)

Another potential quick fix is to install it manually and see if adding the header extension will solve your issue.

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

Comment: i've tried to build the gem manually but still the same issue exist, and every thing is rightly installed (i.e. xcode, gcc, g++ ...)

Comment: Did you try the last step? Remember that the header extension may be needed if you have an older compiler and this means when you try to manually install it, you need to go in and add it before hand. The only problem you are having is with the binder not being able to find the iostream. Additionally, try all of it with an older version of Ruby because I know that some gems will not compile correctly with the newest version of Ruby due some reason that it can't find the devkit properly.

Comment: yup i've tried to add iostream.h instead and the log told me not finding iostream.h header.
when i tried to install it using ruby-2.0.0 it worked but with 2.1.5 it gives the above error.

Comment: When I installed this on Ruby 2.2.3p173 and 2.1.6p336 it worked fine. This may be an issue with the current version you are working with or something is wrong with your ENV.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac OSX el captain, openssl headers are not installed by default therefore try installing openssl. If openssl is already installed try to relink using following command

```
brew link openssl --force
```

See this issue for more detail - https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/643